# Print.js library is printing HTML form but not printing values of input fields

Tags: javascript, forms, printing

I am using print.js library to print a HTML form. it is printing the HTML and form fields but form fields is not containing the given **values** in the printed PDF.

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://printjs-4de6.kxcdn.com/print.min.js"></script>
    
    <form id="eqform" method="post" action="#">
        {{csrf_field()}}
        <div class="tab-content" id="pills-tabContent">
            @includeif('doctor.partials.patientinfo')
            @includeif('doctor.partials.14questions')
            @includeif('doctor.partials.question1')
            @includeif('doctor.partials.question2')
            @includeif('doctor.partials.question3')
            @includeif('doctor.partials.question4')
            @includeif('doctor.partials.question5')
            @includeif('doctor.partials.question6')
            @includeif('doctor.partials.question7')
            @includeif('doctor.partials.question8')
            @includeif('doctor.partials.question9')
            @includeif('doctor.partials.question10')
            @includeif('doctor.partials.question11')
          @includeif('doctor.partials.result')
          <div class="print text-center">
            <button class="btn btn-success" type="button" onclick="printJS('eqform', 'html')">Print</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
```

**The partials are containing different input fileds

Comment: code please...?

Comment: I have added my code in my post.